# Tempo para exclusão, ou exclusão imediata?

Tags: ux

Se preocupando com a experiência do usuário, observando grandes sistemas, como Facebook, Gmail, entre outros... nesses sistemas, na hora de apagar a conta, o sistema sempre avisa sobre um direito de arrependimento, que a conta de fato só vai ser excluída em "x" dias, dando o usuário um tempo para se arrepender.

Entre outros sistemas/empresas menores, a exclusão é informada de imediato, mas através do suporte ainda é possível recuperar a conta durante um determinado tempo.

Quais as vantagens/desvantagens de um modo sobre o outro?

Comment: @DvD Entendo, na verdade a tag `ux` acaba por ser baseada mais em opiniões mesmo, vendo algumas das perguntas sobre ela. Não sei se eu devo editar a pergunta mas recentemente aconteceu algo aqui no StackOverflow, onde um usuário queria apagar sua resposta e deletar sua conta e acabou que teve sua conta temporariamente suspensa pra `acalmar os ânimos`.  Acredito que alguém possa surgir com uma resposta boa, mas se resolverem fechar a pergunta eu entenderei.

Comment: @DvD Seria baseado em opiniões se ele perguntasse qual é o melhor sem especificar o que ele considera melhor. Como a pergunta é de quais são as vantagens de um sobre o outro, você pode listar as vantagens e desvantagens de cada abordagem e algum critério de como escolher de acordo com a situação específica, mas sem dar um veredito. Então, eu acho que essa pergunta fica perto da linha, mas ainda do lado de dentro.

Comment: Tah blz........

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elenco abaixo vantagens da exclusão assíncrona.

Resumo: O usuário tem vantagem no "tempo de arrependimento" quando decide pela guarda de seus dados e em questões de violação de segurança (outra pessoa pode ter pedido a exclusão). A empresa tem vantagem em tomar ação para manter o cliente e para utilizar métodos menos custosos de exclusão de informação. A comunidade envolvida tem vantagem na manutenção de discussões plurais ao reduzir a evasão de usuários quando de discussões mais acaloradas.

---

Vantagens para o usuário quando há o "tempo de arrependimento" na exclusão de uma conta:

- Evitar perda de dados. O usuário tem tempo para exportar dados que achar importantes. O Google, por exemplo, costuma dar ao usuário a opção de exportar seus dados durante o tempo de desativação e fica constantemente lembrando-o disso. Claro, há aí também um "fator psicológico" que pode evitar a perda do cliente.
- Garantir que foi o próprio usuário que solicitou a deleção da conta. O processo de exclusão tende notificar o usuário por e-mail ou outro contato associado, de forma que, caso sua conta tenha sido comprometida e a exclusão solicitada por terceiros, ele tem a oportunidade de cancelar o processo antes de perder a conta.

Há também vantagens para o provedor do serviço e, no caso dos serviços "maiores" como Google e Facebook, há muito provavelmente questões técnicas associadas ao custo da exclusão de dados.

- Uma vantagem negocial está no "fator psicológico" supracitado. Constantes notificações, pedidos de "não vá embora!" e ações promocionais (quando há relação comercial envolvida) podem fazer o usuário mudar de ideia, evitando a perda do cliente.
- Em tempos de *big data* e armazenamento de todo tipo de evento e metadado, cada usuário gera quantidades absurdas de informação que é retida em variados sistemas de armazenamento, *data centers* diferentes ao redor do mundo etc. Sistemas de grande complexidade e encadeamento de serviços associados a uma mesma conta podem representar um custo maior no uso de recursos quando da exclusão dessas informações: o Google (de novo) costuma informar que os dados podem levar tempo para ser excluídos, e isso muito provavelmente se deve ao fato de ser menos custoso ter processos *batch* periódicos de exclusão de dados agrupando sua remoção em um grande processo mensal, por exemplo.
- [Esta resposta no UX](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/85465/why-let-users-deactivate-delete-account) toca também no assunto dos requisitos legais associados à exclusão de dados de clientes. Um site de e-commerce precisa manter informações contábeis suficientes para a declaração de impostos e para possíveis auditorias da receita (no caso dos EUA, mas certamente no Brasil também), devendo reter dados de suas fontes pagadoras. Ao mesmo tempo, na Europa é direito dos usuários terem todos os seus dados excluídos. Assim, a deleção de dados pode necessitar de processamento extra para substituir informações não-fiscais justificando novamente sua execução em *batch*.

Há ainda, como comentado na pergunta, vantagens para a comunidade. Nem sempre a interação online é livre de atritos, e um usuário pode decidir excluir sua conta no calor do momento, como um *rage quit*, e se arrepender posteriormente. Pode-se até argumentar que tal passionalidade seja nociva a uma comunidade, mas também há o contra-argumento de que a pluralidade de gênio e comportamento contribui para a diversidade de interação.

Serviços/empresas que dependem da interação saudável entre os usuários, como o Stack Overflow, Github etc. dependem desse equilíbrio tênue nas relações humanas e podem optar por intervir - na forma do "tempo de arrependimento", por exemplo - nos momentos mais acalorados a fim de garantir o bom andamento da comunidade.

Quanto às desvantagens do uso do "tempo de arrependimento", acredito que sejam associadas à percepção do usuário de que sua intenção não esteja sendo honrada pelo serviço. Entretanto, a não ser para volume reduzido de dados, como pequenas contas de e-commerce em empresas menores, é difícil encontrar processos de eliminação de contas que sejam *online*, sobretudo quando há arquivamento de dados para *backup* de longa data em dispositivos de fita, por exemplo. Assim, ao dizer que a conta foi fechada e que os dados foram eliminados imediatamente, mas na verdade agendando uma exclusão durante processo noturno ou assíncrono entre *data centers*, a empresa estaria mentindo para o usuário.

---

Minha opinião pessoal sobre o assunto é de que, quando da solicitação de cancelamento de conta, desde que meus dados *sejam efetivamente excluídos* dentro de um prazo razoável (não tenho nada contra esperar 30 dias), o processo de exclusão é satisfatório. É penoso pensar, entretanto, na possibilidade de a empresa mentir sobre a exclusão, dado o valor e a vantagem comercial que a posse de informações pessoais representa hoje mais do que nunca. Metadados que permitam inferir hábitos de consumo, informações financeiras, dados de cobrança... é fácil imaginar uma empresa mantendo tais dados sem a permissão do usuário para utilizá-los futuramente em parcerias comerciais.

Comment: Mt bom! Essa redação eh sua mesmo?

Comment: @DvD é minha sim, obrigado =) Escrevi com base na minha experiencia enquanto usuário (a opiniao pessoal do final transpira no texto anterior) e enquanto administrador de sistemas (todo dado é valioso pras empresas, mas mante-lo acessivel online é custoso. Logo, custa "duas vezes" deletá-lo). Usei o link da resposta no UX pra ressaltar a importância da preocupação com os dados pessoais e privacidade dos usuários. Talvez eu tenha sido um tanto redundante nesse aspecto, mas acho que me fiz entender, haha...

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que o melhor mesmo é uma desativação e não exclusão. Assim o usuário pode ativar sua conta a qualquer momento.

Outra coisa que está tendo nos sistemas grandes, como o próprio Gmail que foi citado, é a verificação em 2 passos. Assim só será excluído depois de uma confirmação em um outro dispositivo autorizado.

Nesse caso de "arrependimento", creio que seja bem ruim, pois o usuário solicitou a exclusão e ainda precisa esperar até o dia D para que a conta seja excluída. Deveria ser opcional ou nem existir. Pois na maioria dos casos, o usuário quer uma reposta imediata do que ele está solicitando.

Mas é claro, todos precisam ter pelo menos uma tela anterior de confirmação, para não ter erro. Eu tinha uma assinatura em um site que, para cancelar o serviço, tinha mais de uma tela de confirmação de exclusão de conta. Para mim foi chato ter que passar por mais de uma confirmação.